# History data update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have requirement to check the Auto Parking Membership activity.  When an individual becomes member the details will stored initially with MemberID, MemberShipDate, ActivityDate, ActivityMonthEnd, IsActive, ActiveYTD.  This data will be stored into DW table.  This is **daily** data which we are storing to DW.
The last field ‘ActiveYTD’ has little complex logic.  The default value is ‘Y’, This field value depends on the ‘IsActive’ field.  When IsActive = ‘N’ The ‘ActiveYTD’ field value also updated as ‘N’ from the day the IsActive field value changed from Y to N.
But there is a business rule this IsActive field can be Active and Inactive any number of times. I don’t know why that rule is like that.

**Note**:- If suppose the IsActive field value = ‘N’ on Feb 15 2022 and is inactive until April 20 2022. Certainly the ActivityYTD field will also change from Y to N based on above formula logic. But since the IsActive field changed to ‘Y’ on April 21 2022.  The ActivityYTD will also change to ‘Y’.  But the business definition is when the IsActive field changes to Y from N.  The ActiveYTD field should never be ‘N’ in previous rows. It should be ‘Y’ for all rows from Feb 15 2022 to till date.  So in a scenario if the IsActive value = ‘N’ from Feb 15 2022 till end of the year the ActiveYTD will also be ‘N’ starting Feb 15th 2022.
Both ActivityDate and ActivityMonthEndDate are keys from a dimension table. (eg: - 20220215, 20220228)
Based on the above business logic defined, I have created a query

```
Select mainData.MemberID, mainData.MembershipDate, mainData.ActivityDateKey, mainData.ActivityMonthEndDateKey,  InactiveData.InactiveDate, mainData.IsActive, 
Case When mainData.IsAcitve =’N’ and (mainData.ActivityDateKey/100 >= InactiveData.InactiveDate/100) and (mainData.ActivityDateKey/10000 = InactiveData.InactiveDate/10000) then ‘Y’ else ‘N’ end as AcitveYTD
From History_AutoParkingMemberShip mainData
Left Outer Join
(
     Select MemberID, Max(ActivityDateKey) as InactiveDate
     From AutoParkinigMembership
     Where IsActive = ‘N’ 
     Group by MemberID
) InactiveData on InactiveData.MemberID = MainData.MemberID
```

But this query is not 100% producing correct result.  Because I need to also find if any situation when the IsActive value = ‘Y’ then the previous values wherever I have updated the ActiveYTD value ‘Y’ needed to update to ‘N’.

```
MemberID  MemberShipDate  ActivityDateKey  ActivityMonthEndDateKEy  InactiveDate, IsActive  ActiveYTD

1001      2019/06/17      20220101         20220131                 Null          Y     Y
1001      2019/06/17      20220102         20220131                 Null          Y     Y 
...       ....             ...               ...                    ...          ...    ...
1001      2019/06/17      20220201         20220228                 Null          Y     Y 
1001      2019/06/17      20220215         20220228                 20220420      N     N
...       ....             ...               ...                    ...          ...    ...
1001      2019/06/17      20220420         20220430                 20220420      N     N 
1001      2019/06/17      20220421         20220430                 Null          Y     Y
1001      2019/06/17      20220422         20220430                 Null          Y     Y
```

Now you see the above data where ActiveYTD field should never had value = 'N' because this member 1001 become active again from April 21st 2022. This is little confusion.  Could someone give your thoughts how to improve the query.

Comment: If I understand it correct, ActiveYTD will be same as isActive if the last isActive is 'N'. If the last isActive is 'Y' , ActiveYTD should be 'Y' for the whole year?

Comment: Please also include the sample data

Comment: @Squirrel, the data is too huge.  If there is any way I can attach as a shared file on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Abinash, If the IsActive='N' until the end of the specific year, then only the ActiveYTD='N' other wise the ActiveYTD='Y' forever in that year for that member

Comment: @desi In your dataset, for 20220422 , if IsActive='N' instead of 'Y' what should be the sequence of ActiveYTD?

Comment: @Abinash, if suppose the isActive = 'N' from activityDateKey 20220422 until end of that year.  The ActiveYTD value will also be 'N' from 20220422 onwards and above records i.e. for activityDateKey 20220215 till 20220420 the ActivityYTD will be 'Y'  and not 'N'.

Comment: So if I understand it correct, Pick the last isActive='Y' in a year, mark all previous ActiveYTD as 'Y', if the last record is 'N' mark that ActiveYTD as 'N'.

Comment: @Abinash, you are right. But can we write both conditions in one statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using Window Function.

The idea is to find the last IsActive value with 'Y' of that year sorted by ActivityDateKey.

Any row previous to that should have ActiveYTD as 'Y'.
If there is any record with IsActive='N' after last 'Y', mark those as 'N'.

Below Window Function will give the Count of 'Y' present till the current row.

```sql
COUNT(CASE WHEN IsActive='Y' THEN 1 END) 
OVER( PARTITION BY MemberID,ActivityDateKey/10000
ORDER BY ActivityDateKey Desc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING )
```

**Final Query:**

```
SELECT 
tab.*
,CASE WHEN 
COUNT(CASE WHEN IsActive='Y' THEN 1 END) 
OVER( PARTITION BY MemberID,ActivityDateKey/10000
ORDER BY ActivityDateKey Desc ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) >0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END ActiveYTD
FROM AutoParkinigMembership tab
ORDER BY ActivityDateKey
```

db<>fiddle: [Try here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ca42fc4a2d07c160a647acd7d67f6813)

**Note:** Above fiddle is in sqlserver-2014, but it should work in 2012 as well.

**Dataset:**

| MemberID | MemberShipDate | ActivityDateKey | ActivityMonthEndDateKEy | IsActive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220102 | 20220131 | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220201 | 20220228 | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220215 | 20220228 | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220420 | 20220430 | N |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220421 | 20220430 | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220422 | 20220430 | N |

**Output:**

| MemberID | MemberShipDate | ActivityDateKey | ActivityMonthEndDateKEy | IsActive | ActiveYTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220102 | 20220131 | Y | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220201 | 20220228 | Y | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220215 | 20220228 | Y | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220420 | 20220430 | N | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220421 | 20220430 | Y | Y |
| 1001 | 2019-06-17 | 20220422 | 20220430 | N | N |

Comment: Thanks you for the effort you made to understand the query and time.  The windows function is great.  Thank you sincearly